# Should I use a 10A e-stop on a 15A breaker?

Tags: safety

I want to add an e-stop to my lathe. I'm not sure how much current it draws but I have it on a home 15A breaker.  I was surprised that so many e-stop switches are listed as 10A rating - why so and does this matter?

See below for examples on what comes up when shopping.  Is it worth looking harder and paying more for a higher amp e-stop?  Any reason like regulation why they would list as 10A?

The tiny XT-30 connectors I use all the time (common with rc cars and drones) are rated for 30A so I am just surprised to see such a low amp rating on these e-stops.

[image: shopping example]

Comment: Maybe what matters most is what is written on the body of the switch?  When I zoom in I can see one says  "10A" but also "AC 15" and "DC 13".  Could that indicate it indeed would be rated for 15V if I use it on an AC line?

Comment: Is it really worth saving $10 on this? Get a switch that takes the full training of your circuit.

Comment: If you do not know how much current your lathe draws, stick with 15A. You don't want your E-stop to weld shut or arc when you need it most. How does a lathe not already have an E-stop anyways?

Comment: What make and model is your lathe?  Keep in mind that in order to switch a motor load, your switch needs a *horsepower* rating, not just an amp rating...

Comment: I believe that many/most e-stop switches are not intended to directly interrupt a load but instead to operate relays/contractors that interrupt the load. That may be why they have a lower amperage rating.

Comment: Is there a relay that actually drives the motor? Is it possible a switch that has forward, stop, and reverse? Post a picture of what you have.

Comment: Your graphic was missing some important elements, so I found the four items and added them.  Perhaps they hide that info in the smartphone/app view of Amazon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Everything you linked is dangerous garbage

Because you're buying it straight off Alibaba, or to be more precise, eBay, or to be more precise, the morass of 3rd party sellers on Amazon.

YQBOOM and ARIELE are probably the same seller. There are only a few who sell under thousands of seller names.  It's all the same crud from the Alibaba junkstream. Browse Alibaba.com and you'll find the same items, same photos, with item prices under a dollar in quantity. For a few pennies more they'll individually bag them and stick the Amazon seller's barcode on them. That's what these sellers are doing. It's no surprise that at those prices, they're garbage.

Noting that this question came from the EE stack, I understand the sentiment - in low voltage hobby electronics, it scarcely matters. What can go wrong besides letting out the magic smoke? But **when dealing with AC mains power**, as we do here on DIY, you **really can't fool around**.  As such, our advice here is "Don't buy on Amazon - it's glutted with flaky 3rd party sellers peddling junk, and even listings from Amazon Proper are polluted by their commingling/counterfeit problem".

The way consumer protection law works in the US, there's a huge loophole with items that are shipped from a foreign source by mail. (including drop-shipped via an Amazon warehouse.)

**So where is the bright line?**  It's created by UL, in UL's standards informally known as the "White Book".  UL also serves as a testing lab to [certify](https://forum.digikey.com/t/the-difference-between-ul-listed-and-ul-recognized/954) equipment ("UL Listed") or repair components like a switch ("UR Recognized").  Certain other *Nationally Recognized Testing Labs (NRTL)* can do the same, such as CSA, ETL, BSI, TUV etc.

Generally, such equipment is acquired at electronics suppliers such as mouser.com, Digi-Key, GALCO or Grainger. Most of their switches will be UR-Recognized.  Home Depot seems to have some [sanely priced](https://www.homedepot.com/p/POWERTEC-110-220-Volt-Paddle-Switch-71007/207185617) ones too.

[image]

*Random stop switch sold by Home Depot, $15 full retail. Given HD's high markups on small volume items, the item is at the same price-point as the Amazon crud.  So clearly, UL Listing is not a problem at that price point, and the unlisted crud is a ripoff.*

### Among *recognized* equipment, you must comply with ratings.

The equipment will indeed have ratings - both for continuous amps, and also for certain types of loads - ballast, tungsten, motor, inductive (typically lower numbers for those).  Interrupting inductive loads is hard.  (why the Chinese stuff isn't up for the task).

You must respect the all of the ratings, in the least favorable light.  So for instance if you find one that is 30A interrupt (sounds great) but 11A motor, then you can't use it.  The motor rating may be expressed in horsepower.  You'll need to look at your motor nameplate for that.

> I'm not sure how much current it draws but I have it on a home 15A breaker.

That doesn't matter. People do ridiculous things all the time. However if the saw is UL Listed, and the standard NEMA 5-15P plug came with it, UL would require it be acceptable on a 15A breaker as part of approving the product. There are 1000 details in making a product safe; some people don't want to pay to comply with that, or to be inspected for that.

> I was surprised that so many e-stop switches are listed as 10A rating - why so and does this matter? Any reason like regulation why they would list as 10A?

I guarantee "regulation" has nothing to do with those E-stops.  In fact, it's inadequate - every wood or metal tool I've seen large enough to warrant an e-stop (i.e. not an angle grinder) was bigger than 10A. Perhaps under European 240V power a tool like that can be <10A.  *And mind you, 10A is only the resistive-load rating* -- motor ratings are typically much lower, but cheap as they are they probably don't state any at all.

> The tiny XT-30 connectors I use all the time (common with rc cars and drones) are rated for 30A so I am just surprised to see such a low amp rating on these e-stops.

Those are tiny because weight matters on R/C aircraft. And "connector meltdowns" endanger none but the toy.  It's not like it burns down an apartment block.  When AC mains power is being dealt with, things are a great deal more burly. *At least if UL has anything to say about it.*

Comment: Seems a little bit broadly pejorative; that stuff is fine for switching _signals_, not loads. When (properly) used to send a 5v DC or even 24v AC trigger to a controller, UL or human safety concerns are basically mute. If it's so crappy it doesn't even cleanly/reliably switch that's one thing, but if it works and it's used right, it can add safety rather than detract it.

Comment: @Dandavis Nothing pejorative here. In North America we have a "bright line" standard as to what is safe and what is not, clearly defined by UL.  This stuff absolutely does not meet it.  If it could, they would get the requisite certifications, which would greatly expand their customer base.  *They can't*.  That bright-line standard takes the "judgment" out of it. This isn't about China, it's about stuff purpose-built below standard, and Amazon sellers hogging all the savings while representing the product as legitimate.

Comment: Also you are incorrect about the switch being "properly" used for low voltage control.  It is advertised for 250V and 10A, and given that, OP's expectation that it should be usable as a line-voltage interrupt *is entirely reasonable*. A UL listed switch of same rating would handle that all day all night.  By saying "properly" you seem to be advocating for a secret shibboleth where "we all understand" the Alibaba crud can only be used at a fraction of the advertised spec. Nonsense! Let them rate it accurately. Also, UL listings are a great deal more than that.

Comment: Keep in mind those are chinese amps; you have to divide by 4 to get metric...